# Modify GeoServer Caching Defaults via REST

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, rest

I'm working on some shell scripts to configure GeoServer instances using the REST endpoints, but I've become stuck with the GeoWebCache caching defaults. Is there any way to modify the gwc-cs.xml file using the REST endpoints for GeoServer or GWC?

I've been through the docs, but I can only see how to change the global settings. I can't see how to change the default grid sets, cache layers by default, etc.

The best alternative I can think of is to copy an XML file to the GeoServer data-dir and call the reload REST endpoint to reload the config.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look in the `resource` endpoint - on my machine http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/resource/gwc-gs.xml
gives me, usually I `GET` it, edit and then `PUT` it back.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GeoServerGWCConfig>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <directWMSIntegrationEnabled>true</directWMSIntegrationEnabled>
  <WMSCEnabled>true</WMSCEnabled>
  <TMSEnabled>true</TMSEnabled>
  <securityEnabled>false</securityEnabled>
  <innerCachingEnabled>false</innerCachingEnabled>
  <persistenceEnabled>true</persistenceEnabled>
  <cacheProviderClass>
class org.geowebcache.storage.blobstore.memory.guava.GuavaCacheProvider
</cacheProviderClass>
  <cacheConfigurations>
    <entry>
      <string>
class org.geowebcache.storage.blobstore.memory.guava.GuavaCacheProvider
</string>
      <InnerCacheConfiguration>
        <hardMemoryLimit>16</hardMemoryLimit>
        <policy>NULL</policy>
        <concurrencyLevel>4</concurrencyLevel>
        <evictionTime>120</evictionTime>
      </InnerCacheConfiguration>
    </entry>
  </cacheConfigurations>
  <cacheLayersByDefault>true</cacheLayersByDefault>
  <cacheNonDefaultStyles>true</cacheNonDefaultStyles>
  <metaTilingX>4</metaTilingX>
  <metaTilingY>4</metaTilingY>
  <gutter>0</gutter>
  <defaultCachingGridSetIds>
    <string>EPSG:4326</string>
    <string>osgb</string>
    <string>EPSG:900913</string>
  </defaultCachingGridSetIds>
  <defaultCoverageCacheFormats>
    <string>image/png</string>
    <string>image/jpeg</string>
  </defaultCoverageCacheFormats>
  <defaultVectorCacheFormats>
    <string>image/png</string>
    <string>image/jpeg</string>
  </defaultVectorCacheFormats>
  <defaultOtherCacheFormats>
    <string>image/png</string>
    <string>image/jpeg</string>
  </defaultOtherCacheFormats>
  <lockProviderName>nioLock</lockProviderName>
</GeoServerGWCConfig>
```

Comment: Thats what I thought, and I can PUT the new gwc-gs.xml file in the right location. The problem then is the REST endpoint for `geoserver/rest/reload` and `gwc/rest/reload` do not seem to pick up the updated file. There is a another question about it here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133973/how-to-reload-the-geowebcache-gwc-gs-xml-manually.